# Ember.js: Computed property of model not rendering in component's reference on change

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The issue I am experiencing is quite clearly expressed in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wopita/3/edit?html,js,output), where the computed property isFinito does not change in the template along with the value of isFinished.  Is this a feature of components, that they can't listen to computed properties of models passed to them ?  If so, how can I achieve this.  It seems like a very common need but no matter how much I searched about this, I couldn't find something that duplicates this problem or solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with observers - the cause is property access. Consider the following line:

```
return (this.isFinished ? "SI" :"NON");
```

This is *always* going to return `NON` because `this.isFinished` is *always* falsy (it's `undefined`). Ember-Data doesn't put data directly on the model instances, it just puts computed properties there. `this.isFinished` doesn't exist. If you use Ember's `get()` method, it works fine:

```
return (this.get('isFinished') ? "SI" :"NON");
```

As a general rule, *always* use `get()` when dealing with Ember objects. I know it's a little annoying at first, but you get used to it and it helps avoid a lot of issues.

Comment: OMG, can't believe I missed that, thanks a bunch @GJK !